# Changing the first(or any) character of an array string value

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, set, return

Say I have an array with string values such as:

```
var foo = ["Hello", "World"];
```

I can return the first character of each array element by doing:

```
foo[0][0]; // Will return "H"
foo[1][0]; // Will return "W"
```

However, when attempting to change the value of those characters using a similar method, it doesn't work. What I mean is that doing this does not work:

```
foo[0][0] = "J"; // Will not change "H" to "J".
```

It's not a huge issue since I know alternative ways to do so such as:

```
foo[0] = "J"+foo[0].substsring(1); // Hello --> Jello
```

But I'm curious as to why the previous method does not work? EDIT: Did some fiddling around and apparently it doesn't work with strings at all to begin with, not just strings in arrays. I guess I was under the false impression that strings act just like arrays. I can return certain characters by calling it's position in the string similar to how calling an array index works, but changing said index doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Javascript [***String***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) reference:

> For character access using bracket notation, attempting to **delete** or
>   **assign** a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties
>   involved are neither writable nor configurable. (See
>   [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more information.)

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, that is, they cannot be altered.

This:

```
foo[0][0] = "J";
```

Doesn't work because you are attempting to modify the string stored at position 0 in the `foo` array.

This:

```
foo[0] = "J"+foo[0].substsring(1);
```

does work because you aren't trying to modify a string, you are trying to **replace** the element at position 0 in the `foo` array with an **entirely new** string.

Answer (score 0):

All primitive data types in JavaScript are immutable.

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures):

> Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so they cannot be changed unless you create a new string and store the new value inside of that string.  You cannot change a character within a string, The string manipulation methods such as trim, substring etc.

From substring method  - The result is a String value, not a String object.
var foo = ["Hello", "World"];

foo[0][0] = "J"; 
console.log(foo);

foo[0] = "J"+foo[0].substring(1);

console.log(foo);

Notice if you change 
var foo = [1, "World"];
foo[0][0] = "J"; 
It works, since it's not a string

Check this out : https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.substring

If start is larger than end, they are swapped.

The following steps are taken: From the link above

```
Let O be ? RequireObjectCoercible(this value).
Let S be ? ToString(O).
Let len be the number of elements in S.
Let intStart be ? ToInteger(start).
If end is undefined, let intEnd be len; else let intEnd be ? ToInteger(end).
Let finalStart be min(max(intStart, 0), len).
Let finalEnd be min(max(intEnd, 0), len).
Let from be min(finalStart, finalEnd).
Let to be max(finalStart, finalEnd).
Return a String whose length is to - from, containing code units from S, namely the code units with indices from through to - 1, in ascending order.
```